# How do I start setInterval only when input element has focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have an input element in the body of a page. And I've created a `setInterval` method. Now what I want is when the tab in which my page is open has **focus** (i.e., `$(window).foucs();`), and when my mouse cursor is inside input field (i.e., I've clicked inside input field and it's inside the input), the `setInterval` should start. And it should continue until the input loses focus, i.e., the cursor is not inside input.

So far, I've tried this but it's not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).focus(function(){
    if(("input").is(":focus")){
      var aa=setInterval(newFunc, 2000);
      function newFunc(){...........}
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: you could add a check inside `newFunc` that would turn off the interval when the input is no longer focused.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$("input").on("focus", function () {
    var aa = setInterval(newFunc, 2000);
    function newFunc(){...........}
});
```

Or to do it on focus out, change `focus` to `focusout`.

See: https://api.jquery.com/focus/ and https://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Comment: No sir. It would start interval on first click in the input field. What I want is run it till when the cursor is inside input field. It should stop as soon as cursor moves out, i.e., input loses focus.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the variable in the common scope between a focus and blur handler for the input element.

```
var aa;
$("input").focus(function(){
    aa = setInterval(newFunc, 2000);
  function newFunc() {
    ...
  }
})
$("input").blur(function(){
    clearInterval(aa);
})
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Looks like it would help. But can' it be done using :focus selector?

Comment: Is that necessary?

Comment: Sir this is my actual code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36774893/how-do-i-check-if-input-field-is-in-focus-or-not So clearly I posted wrong query here. Could you please answer this one?