# How do I check if input field is in focus or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to send an Ajax request only when my input field is in focus (i.e., cursor is inside it. Here's my code:

```
function anewFunc() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var chatattr = $(".chatwindow").css("visibility");
        var chattitle = $("#hideid").text();
        if (chatattr == "visible") {
            if (MY INPUT FIELD HAS FOCUS) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'seen1.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: "ctitle="+chattitle,
                    success: function(result9) {},
                    error: function() {}
                });
            }
        } else {
            $.post("seendefault.php");
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var zzz = setInterval(anewFunc, 2000);
});
```

Now I don't know how to check every time the input has focus or not. Is there any jQuery solution for it?

EDIT: A few answers has suggested me :focus. So I tried this for trial:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                           if($("#msgtypeid").is(":focus")){
                               alert("Hello");
                           }
                           });
```

HTML:

```
<form id="chatform" name="form4" method="post" required enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input id="msgtypeid" type="text" name="cmessage" autocomplete="off" autofocus/>
        </form>
```

But it's not working. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Read the docs: https://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: did you try document.activeElement

Comment: After edit: it gets called only once...that is when the document is ready

Comment: Ok @SamGhatak how can I improve it?

Comment: I'm trying first the trial code that I've added in the end. How do I display alert?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need this type of a checking:

```
var hasFocus = $('#idOfTheInputElement').is(':focus');
if(hasFocus){
    //logic here
}
```

Comment: I think you should put the checking inside the `anewFunc()`.....you can remove the document.ready part from inside...and bind the function with the event that supposed to trigger the call

Answer (score 6):

Add a `focus`-event handler to your `input` element, and your callback function will be called every time the element gets focused.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('example').addEventListener('focus', function() {
        alert('The input is focused.');
    });
});
```

[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k78804wm/)

Comment: Concise, works (tested on Android 4.4.2) and pure JS, just what I was looking for, thank you Marat.

Answer (score 3):

With Jquery 1.6+ :

```
$("..").is(":focus")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example showing a few different options:

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNBqmJ)

HTML

```
<input type='text' class="is-focus">

<input type="text" class="isActiveElement">

<input type="text" class="focused">
```

JS

```
$('input').on('click', function() {

  if ($('.is-focus').is(':focus')) {
    alert('focused')
  }

  if ($(document.activeElement).is('.isActiveElement')) {
    alert('isActiveAlement')
  }

  if($('.focused:focus').length) {
    alert(':focus')
  }
});
```

Comment: As you currently have it, you're not calling the function until the document is ready. So no, you do not need to include it in that function.

Comment: @VikasKumar : you will need it to set the interval, second use of document.ready inside the function newFunc is not required...instead, put a check there

Comment: Got it @SamGhatak I just din't define when should the if condition start. I put the :focus code inside a new setInterval and it worked when I clicked inside input! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First, take the $(document).ready out of your function.  You only need to call it once, not on interval.

```
var myInterval= null;  // in case you decide to clear it later.

function anewFunc() {

        var chatattr = $(".chatwindow").css("visibility");
        var chattitle = $("#hideid").text();
        var chatinput = $("#inputid");
        var chatText = chatinput.val();
        if (chatattr == "visible") {
            if (chatinput.is(":focus")) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'seen1.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    // if you're posting data, it should be as a json object
                    data: {"ctitle" : chattitle, "text":chatText}, 
                    success: function(result9) {},
                    error: function() {}
                });
            }
        } else {
            $.post("seendefault.php");
        }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    myInterval = setInterval(anewFunc, 2000);
});
```

This change calls your ready function ONCE, sets the interval, and gets the input field's value when it is focused.

Answer (score 1):

The javascript event listener `focus` would only get fired once you focus the input box which is not ideal if you're doing multiple conditional statements .

I find having the expression `document.activeElement == document.getElementById("input-box-id")` more convenient in this regard .

Answer (score 0):

You can use "is":

```
if ($("input").is(":focus")) {

....
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use even odd method

```
var i = 0;

$('.chatwindow').on('focus blur', function () {

  i += 1;

  var tog = function (someNum) {

     if ((someNum % 2) === 1) {
        return true;
     } else {
        return false;
     }
  };


  if (tog(i) === true) {
     // make ajax function

  } else {
    // do something else
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to type a bunch of scripts, just add some simple css:

```
#yourInputOrWhatever:focus {
    /* Your New Code Here */
}
```

Comment: OP wants to send an Ajax request on focus, not change the appearance of focus